# How can I prove that this Group is Abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$(G,\cdot)$ a group.
If $\exists n\in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $(a\cdot b)^{n+i}=a^{n+i}\cdot b^{n+i}$ for   $i=0,1,2.$ $\forall a,b \in G$. 
Prove that $(G,\cdot)$ is Abelian.
I'm not sure how to prove this. Why $i$ must be 0 ,1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $(a\cdot b)^{n+2}=a^{n+2}\cdot b^{n+2}$ we can multiply by $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ on the left and right to get
$$(b\cdot a)^{n+1}=a^{n+1}\cdot b^{n+1}=(a\cdot b)^{n+1},$$
the latter equality holding by assumption. Repeating this trick we get
$$(b\cdot a)^n=a^n\cdot b^n=(a\cdot b)^n,$$
and dividing these two left hand sides and right hand sides of the above by eachother yields
$$b\cdot a = a\cdot b.$$